# Hover effect on js and issue with mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've a problem with a joomla template in a portfolio page.
The problem is quite simple to describe: with pcs devices when you pass the mouse over a photo (of the portfolio) it appears a dark window (hover effect) that permit the user to enlarge the photo or to enter on photo details ( in the dark window that appears, in a semi-trasparency effect, there's two icons that manage these 2 options).
With a resolution under 768px the hover action clearly doesn't work (it has done for mobile devices) and if i click on the photo, it says that content can not be loaded. When i click on the photo with mobile devices the dark window appears and shows me the two icons that permite me to zoom the photo or to enter in the detail. The mechanism is controlled by a custom js that the author has created to manage the effect, but i don't know too much javascript..Can you help me?
The script is:

```
    var currentWindowWidth = $f(window).width();
     if(currentWindowWidth >= 768){
    $f('.viewport').mouseenter(function(e) {
        $f(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '178',   left: '-20', top: '-20', width: '260'}, 100);
        $f(this).children('span').fadeIn(200);
        $f(this).children('span').addClass('dark-background');
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $f(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '138', left: '-0', top: '0', width: '220'}, 100);
        $f(this).children('span').fadeOut(200);
        $f(this).children('span').removeClass('dark-background');
    });
}
```

I could appreciate if you can help me.
Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out or delete the if

```
 // var currentWindowWidth = $f(window).width();
 // if(currentWindowWidth >= 768){
$f('.viewport').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $f(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '178',   left: '-20', top: '-20', width: '260'}, 100);
    $f(this).children('span').fadeIn(200);
    $f(this).children('span').addClass('dark-background');
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    $f(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '138', left: '-0', top: '0', width: '220'}, 100);
    $f(this).children('span').fadeOut(200);
    $f(this).children('span').removeClass('dark-background');
});
```

// }

Answer (score 1):

I would try with `touchend` event so when mobile/touch users touch the image they get the effect.

```
var currentWindowWidth = $f(window).width();
//if(currentWindowWidth >= 768){
    $f('.viewport').on("mouseenter touchend", function(e) {
        $f(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '178',   left: '-20', top: '-20', width: '260'}, 100);
        $f(this).children('span').fadeIn(200);
        $f(this).children('span').addClass('dark-background');
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $f(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '138', left: '-0', top: '0', width: '220'}, 100);
        $f(this).children('span').fadeOut(200);
        $f(this).children('span').removeClass('dark-background');
    });
//}
```

This will not remove the effect, so if the mobile/touch user touches multiple images - every one they touch will get the darkened effect.

*edit:* tomjm also made a good point. you need to remove the if statement